# Why does trying to replace an image source browse me to the image instead?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript (only a couple of days of reading a book) and I am stuck on this code snippet. I have looked at it over and over again but cannot seem to figure out why it is not working. I am sure it is something really simple that I have just overlooked, and I just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at this.

The code is supposed to update a placeholder image on a page without the page having to reload. But when I am clicking on the link of an image, it is taking me to the link where the image is located instead of replacing the placeholder image. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Image Gallery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/showPic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Snapshots</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="images/cat.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="A Cat">Cat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/night.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="Night">Night</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/coke.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="Coke">Coke</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/sport.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="Sports">Sport</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/mnms.png" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="MnM's">MnM's</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/kid.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="A Kid">Kid</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br />

    <img id="placeholder" src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Place Holder Image" />

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JavaScript function I am using to get this done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showPic(whichpic) { 
    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href"); 
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder"); 
    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source);
}

</script>
```

Comment: where is this "placeholder" that you are accessing by document.getElementById ?

Comment: BTW, there's a better way to attach events to a collection of DOM elements (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614869/attaching-events-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, I just tried out your code and it works perfectly fine under FF 3.6. Are you sure that your images are located in the images folder relative to the HTML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script uses

```
document.getElementById("placeholder");
```

to get the place holder element reference. Be sure that you set your HTML elements' id attributes if you want to be able to use this function. So, whichever is your placeholder element, (i guess it is the IMG tag at bottom) set id="placeholder" attribute.

since you are starting, have a look at documentations :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID

From your problem it seems that you are linking to javaScript. Make sure you are pointing to right location in your

If adding div and checking your .js file's location does not help, you try to open the page on "Firefox", then click on the links and look for script errors. How to do that is :
From Tools menu, choose Error console.

This will give you useful info on what is going wrong. If you have error and can't figure out what is going on, post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **id** attribute of **img** tag

```
<img id="placeholder" src="images/placeholder.jpg" title="Place Holder Image" />
```

Btw, since you are claiming XHTML, make sure you close your tags.

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga - My bad. Edited the wrong comment. I've removed mine.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I changed the line of code to add this:

[code]<img src="images/placeholder.jpg" title="Place Holder Image" id="placeholder">[/code]

But it still did not work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: close the image tag properly <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" title="Place Holder Image" id="placeholder" /> , note the "/>" at the end instead of just ">"